# How do we get a cool popup when a question is asked?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just visited SciFi.SE to post a "can anyone remember this book?" question when the most amazing popup appeared!

[image]

I want a cool popup like this! A popup with some concise, succinct, and *very direct* recommendations about how to write a good question.

So, how do we activate a popup like this on our site?

*(Or, are we stuck with yet another Stack Exchange cookie-cutter solution that fits Stack Overflow really well and no one else?)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That popup is already active network-wide.

But it is *only* shown the first time you ask a question on a site. See the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/295232)